# Asp.Net Identity - Logged Out On App Pool Recycle

Tags: asp.net-identity

Everything in our Asp.Net Identity configuration is set to maximize the length of login - IsPersistent, StayLoggedIn, long expire time, sliding window, etc.

However it appears all of this is defeated by a simple AppPool recycle. These usually occur when we deploy, which typically happens once per day. If that doesn't get us, the default AppPool recycle time is 29 hours.

We've disabled the automatic recycle time but we still would like users' logins to survive past a deploy of the code. There must be some way to resolve this?

For the curious:

I can prove AppPool recycle is the cause because I can tap Recycle... in IIS on the AppPool and boom, my login dies, even though my cookie's fine. I can do this over and over back to back and it will consistently kill my login.

We don't have a Machine Key explicitly set because we use a single server with a hot spare, and everything I've read about Machine Key suggests setting it should be unnecessary unless we're using a Web Farm, which we are not.